# Ternary operator when binding values

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Whats the most effective way of binding an attribute depending on the variable value when looping through a list?

Eg if status is "Approved", the `color` on my `Badge` should be "green", if status is "Rejected", `color` should be "red", and if status is "Pending", the `color` should be yellow.

Is there a more effective/cleaner way than the following:

```
let orders = [
    { id: "31231", ..., status: "Approved" },
    { id: "321211", ..., status: "Pending" },
    { id: "93218", ..., status: "Rejected" },
  ];

....

{#each order as {id, status}, i}

// other stuff being looped here
<Item>
... 

 {#if status == "Approved"}
   <Badge color="green">{status}</Badge>
 {:else if status == "Rejected"}
   <Badge color="red">{status}</Badge>
 {:else}
   <Badge color="yellow">{status}</Badge>
 {/if}

</Item>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For predetermined cases like these I personally like to use a simple lookup object:

```html
const statusColor = {
    "Approved": "green",
    "Pending": "yellow",
    "Rejected": "red",
};

let orders = [
    { id: "31231", ..., status: "Approved" },
    { id: "321211", ..., status: "Pending" },
    { id: "93218", ..., status: "Rejected" },
  ];

....

{#each order as {id, status}, i}

// other stuff being looped here
<Item>
... 

 <Badge color={statusColor[status]}>{status}</Badge>
</Item>
{/each}
```

If you find this lookup object is used in several different files, consider defining it elsewhere (e.g. in a `lib/constants.js` file along with other such values) and importing it wherever needed.

Answer (score 2):

A more effective way would be to use a kind of mapping

```html
<script>
const color_map = {
  "Approved": "green",
  "Rejected": "red",
  "Pending": "yellow"
}
</script>

<Badge color={color_map[status]}>{status}</Badge>
```

This does however assume there are no 'unknown' statuses in which case the map will return `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Make a map

```
const statusColor = {
  Approved: 'green',
  Pending: 'yellow',
  Rejected: 'red'
}
....
<Badge color={statusColor[status]}>{status}</Badge>
```